# How to create OpenID Provider with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, openid, openid-provider

I finished studying OpenID to understand its main features. The next step is an OpenID Provider program for my clients. My goal is to develop with SpringBoot (without using Spring Security).

I noticed that I have OpenID Connect, MITREid as options. But none presents a tutorial on how to create a customer and supplier of one.

On another topic, found links from IBM, however, are all out of thin air.

It would be of great importance a simple tutorial as a kick start for the OpenID Provider development for my application.

Answer (score 6):

I appreciate that this is a year after the OP's question, but I found some more information whilst doing my own research into the same subject.

[There is a Spring Boot port of MitreId available here](https://github.com/simpledynamics/openid-connect-server-spring-boot)
which I found very useful as a working example.

I also want to mention that the Mitre is [available as a Maven Dependency](https://github.com/mitreid-connect/OpenID-Connect-Java-Spring-Server/wiki/Maven-Dependency)

I hope this helps the next person visiting this page !

Comment: Thanks for this. Any chance you could give a brief explanation of how to use the example? I have it in Eclipse but don't know how to run it. TIA!

Answer (score 5):

*Update 2022*

Spring Authorization Server is a supported Spring Security project that [should go GA in November 2022](https://spring.io/blog/2022/07/28/spring-authorization-server-is-going-1-0)

*Original*

It [rarely makes sense](https://www.thoughtworks.com/radar/platforms/auth0) for someone to roll-their-own OpenID Connect Provider. It's not trivial. MitreID Connect even uses Spring Security for part of their code. If you want to use MitreID Connect but as "spring-boot", you can look at [some](https://github.com/mitreid-connect/OpenID-Connect-Java-Spring-Server/issues/670#issuecomment-258219099) [ports](https://github.com/mitreid-connect/OpenID-Connect-Java-Spring-Server/pull/1067) of mitreid connect to spring-boot and java config...but I'm not certain they are maintained.

By the way, what do you mean by

> none presents a tutorial on how to create a customer and supplier of one.

Do you mean how to use mitreid connect?

- [Documentation](https://github.com/mitreid-connect/OpenID-Connect-Java-Spring-Server/wiki)
- [Example provider](https://github.com/mitreid-connect/example-openid-connect-overlay)
- [Example client](https://github.com/mitreid-connect/simple-web-app)

Anyway, unless you really know what you're doing, I'd recommend working with an existing OpenID Connect Provider. See: http://openid.net/developers/certified/

Answer (score 2):

Meanwhile there is a Spring communtity-driven project: [Spring Authorization Server](https://github.com/spring-projects-experimental/spring-authorization-server) it was [announced](https://spring.io/blog/2020/04/15/announcing-the-spring-authorization-server) in April 2020 on Spring Blog.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security.experimental</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Its current version is 0.1.1 [available](https://spring.io/blog/2021/05/10/spring-authorization-server-0-1-1-available-now) since May 2021. (Version 0.1.0 is [available](https://spring.io/blog/2021/02/11/spring-authorization-server-0-1-0-available-now) since February 2021)

---

Tuturial: Baeldung [Spring Security OAuth Authorization Server](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-oauth-auth-server)